# VS Code note recognizing python interpreter from venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I keep all my projects in a folder called 'Projects' and have a venv in each project. I have the venv path setting in VS Code set to my Projects folder path, and when I use the Select Python Interpreter it recognizes the venv in my folder and says it is selected, however the venv is not being recognized because it won't recognize the packages I have imported.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXf9C.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the python interpreter after starting VScode? From within VScode.

Answer (score 2):

So how I solved it was deleting the venv I created inside the project folder and creating a folder inside the project folder called venv where I installed the virtual environment. From there, the default paths in vscode were able to detect my venv and it was able to run. I'm not sure why it made a difference but it's working now!